# Sweet Alert not getting called unless dummy echo statement in place

Tags: javascript, sweetalert

I have a very strange bug using Sweet Alert.  Hoping someone can provide some troubleshooting suggestions.  Please view the video [here](https://henryder.tinytake.com/sf/MjU4MzI4OF83NzcwOTQ3) to see the strangeness of it.  I will also describe it briefly below:

It's part of a user login portion of code.

The function calls Sweet Alert to provide a popup alert.  It works when I insert a dummy echo statement such as `echo "REACHED PREP LOGIN";` I get the popup.  If this is not in, there is no popup.  The code is below:

```
function prepLogin ($id, $username, $remember, $email){
    $_SESSION['id'] = $id;
    $_SESSION['username'] = $username;
    $_SESSION['email'] = $email;

    $fingerprint = md5($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'] . $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']);
    $_SESSION['last_active'] = time();
    $_SESSION['fingerprint'] = $fingerprint;

    if($remember === "yes"){
        rememberMe($id);
    }
    //call sweet alert 
    //echo 'REACHED PREP LOGIN'.'<br>';
    echo $welcome = "<script type=\"text/javascript\">
                            swal({
                            title: \"Welcome back $username!\",
                            text: \"You're being logged in.\",
                            type: 'success',
                            timer: 3000,
                            showConfirmButton: false });
                            setTimeout(function(){
                               window.location.href = '../../index.php';
                            }, 3000);
                        </script>";
}
```

Does not make any sense to me why an echo statement would nullify a script function...  There must be a way to troubleshoot this.  Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you open up your console you'll see a error from Sweat Alert saying it is being injected before the dom is fully loaded. If you wrap your swal call like so

```
    echo $welcome = "<script type=\"text/javascript\">

document.addEventListener(\"DOMContentLoaded\", function(){
                            swal({
                            title: \"Welcome back $username!\",
                            text: \"You're being logged in.\",
                            type: 'success',
                            timer: 3000,
                            showConfirmButton: false });
                            setTimeout(function(){
                               window.location.href = '../../index.php';
                            }, 3000);
});
                        </script>";
```

Then swal wont fire until the whole dom has been loaded. Im guess when you added another echo statement it renders the whole dom before the script tag get ran.